# C# Dictionary doesn't find the key after being added

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I've made a simple program that will read functions in a text file splitted by a new line and execute it just like a programming language. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace My_Project
{
class Program
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> variables = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        //string code = args[0];
        string code = File.ReadAllText(@"TEXT FILE LOCATION HERE");
        var lines = code.Split('\n');
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            char[] lineInCharArray = line.ToCharArray();
            if (lineInCharArray[0] == '-')
            {
                string variablename = (lineInCharArray[1]).ToString();
                string value = line.Replace("-" + variablename, "");
                Console.WriteLine("VARIABLE DEFINED: " + variablename + " - " + value);
                variables.Add(variablename, value);
            }
            if (lineInCharArray[0] == '*')
            {
                if (lineInCharArray[1] == '*')
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string requestedVariable = line.Replace("**", "");
                        Console.WriteLine("REQUESTED VARIABLE: " + 
requestedVariable);
                        string printedValue = variables[requestedVariable];
                        Console.WriteLine(printedValue);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: ");
                        List<string> hhh = variables.Keys.ToList();
                        foreach (string item in hhh)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("--: " + item);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    string printedValue = line.Replace("*", "");
                    Console.WriteLine(printedValue);
                }
            }
            if (lineInCharArray[0] == '+')
            {
                string variable = variables[lineInCharArray[1].ToString()];
                Int32 variableInInt = Convert.ToInt32(variable);
                Int32 incrementation = Convert.ToInt32(line.Replace("+" + variable, ""));
                for (int i = 0; i < incrementation + 1; i++)
                {
                    variableInInt++;
                }
                variables[lineInCharArray[1].ToString()] = variableInInt.ToString();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

## Input (text file)

```
-a12 // Set a variable named 'a' and set the value to 12
-j8  // Set a variable named 'j' and set the value to 8
**j // Print the value of the variable of 'j'
**a // Print the value of the variable of 'a'
```

## Problem:

The code outputs the following:

```
VARIABLE DEFINED: a - 12
VARIABLE DEFINED: j - 8
REQUESTED VARIABLE: j
ERROR:
--: a
--: j
REQUESTED VARIABLE: a
12
```

The code successfully assigned `a` to 12 and `j` to `8`, but fails to print `j` (`a` is fine though). It says that the key `j` wasn't found on the dictionary even though the program did add `j`. The solution should output the following:

```
VARIABLE DEFINED: a - 12
VARIABLE DEFINED: j - 8
REQUESTED VARIABLE: j
8
REQUESTED VARIABLE: a
12
```

Comment: Try `Console.WriteLine("REQUESTED VARIABLE: [" + requestedVariable + "]");` and tell me what you see.

Comment: @MikeNakis `]EQUESTED VARIABLE: [j`

Comment: you have a hidden character at the end of the line **j, maybe a space or linefeed, so it is different than just `j`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the question I asked in a comment, and the answer you posted in a comment, it is obvious that what you have is a line feed character (`\r`) at the end of `j`, so what appears to be `"j"` is not exactly `"j"`; instead, it is `"j\r"`.

So, you need to clean each line that you read from your file from control characters.  In fact, you should clean them from any character which is not part of a valid identifier.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I solved the problem by replacing `var lines = code.Split('\n');` into `var lines = code.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);`